# Serialize Java classes to XMI from code

Tags: java, xml, serialization, xmlserializer

I am looking for Java library which would allow me to convert Java classes to the UML and serialize it(save) to [XMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Metadata_Interchange) file. I want to do so from java code.

Please suggest, any help appreciated.